# Can't start odoo service

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo-10

I'am working with odoo10 and ubuntu 16, when I tried to start the service odoo, `/etc/init.d/odoo-server start`, nothing happend, and if I seek it's process i find nothing, `ps ax | grep odoo`, 
and I can't see error using log file

Comment: using terminal : change the current directory using 'cd' to the directory including 'odoo-bin' then use 'python odoo-bin'

Comment: and if you want to use odoo as a system service and being able to start it automatically when the system boots I think this link will be usefull https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=opzcDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=automatically+start+odoo&source=bl&ots=15qJ_3Zm-F&sig=zVadbJCtT5H1sFyoA_n4bv6FmSY&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=automatically%20start%20odoo&f=false

Comment: @SOS-Mona Thanks for help, this is a part of problem

Comment: so did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

using terminal : change the current directory using 'cd' to the directory including 'odoo-bin' then use 'python odoo-bin'

and if you want to use odoo as a system service and being able to start it automatically when the system boots I think  [this link will be usefull](https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=opzcDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=automatically%20start%20odoo&source=bl&ots=15qJ_3Zm-F&sig=zVadbJCtT5H1sFyoA_n4bv6FmSY&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=automatically%20start%20odoo&f=false)

Comment: Thanks, this is part of sol,

Comment: I have keeped my own addons, and I just rienstalled odoo

Comment: The probeleme source is postgres role

Answer (score 0):

Just set permission for both conf file and service file properly as per

http://blog.balvantramani.com/2017/09/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Also check DAEMON=/opt/odoo/odoo-bin(for odoo10) (this is different for odoo 8 or 9)

Comment: There is no problem with permission

Comment: Then sure it is something wrong in file. Just copy both files from /opt/odoo/debian...